# when I fetch data from server side, I got an error which is...ManageInventory.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios

**Here is my index.js from server**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const items = require('./data.json');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello....Assalamualaikum')
})
app.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    res.send(items);
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening from', port)
})
```

**Here is ManageInventory.js from front end**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const ManageInventory = () => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/items'
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    return (
        <>
            <h1>This is manage Inventory page</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default ManageInventory;
```

why show the res.json() is not a function?

Comment: _"why show the res.json() is not a function"_... because you're using Axios and not the Fetch API. You want `res => res.data`. See [Axios - Response Schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema). **Voting to close as a typo**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

write res.data not res.json()
Axios takes care of parsing the response automatically for us, so we don't have to call any additional methods.

Comment: _"we don't have to call any additional methods"_... you couldn't if you wanted to. Those methods simply **do not exist**.

Answer (score -1):

Whwn i'am call axios like below then my problem is solved. Thank you all for your kind helpful information.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/items')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
```